# How do division-by-zero exceptions work?

Tags: c++, exception

How is division calculated on compiler/chip level?

And why does C++ always throw these exceptions at run-time instead of compile-time (in case the divisor is known to be zero at compile time)?

Comment: These should be two separate questions.

Comment: Why don't programmers check for zero before dividing?

Comment: Thomas: because chances of a zero being passed in are very low, because the exception thing works great, because an extra check is extra work for the processor, which we might not want in a high-occurance loop.

Comment: g++, at least, gives a compile-time warning if it sees you obviously dividing by zero:  temp.cpp:5: warning: division by zero in ‘1 / 0’
l

Answer (score 2):

It totally depend on the compiler. You can if you want write an extension for your compiler to check this kind of problem.

For example visual C++:

- [Division by zero Compiler error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byc7w2kb.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1. It depends. Some processors have a hardware divide instruction. Some processors have to do the calculation is software.
2. Some C++ compilers don't trap at runtime either. Often because there is no hardware support for trapping on divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

1. At the chip level, division is of course done with circuits.  [Here's an overview](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~squire/cs411_l10.html) of binary division circuitry.
2. Because the C++ compiler just isn't checking for divisors that are guaranteed to equal 0.  It could check for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Big lookup tables. Remember those multiplication tables from school? Same idea, but division instead of multiplication. Obviously not every single number is in there, but the number is broken up into chunks and then shoved through the table.
2. The division takes place at runtime, not at compile time. Yes, the compiler could see that the divisor is zero, but most people are not expected to write an invalid statement like that.